# D3.js updating data in packed hierarchy changes wrong elements

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have some hierarchical data which is being packed to form a bubble chart, this works fine however when I update the data and apply a new pack the wrong elements are updated so they transition to the wrong location within the circle. It seems to be updating the data based on its index but I can’t find any way to tell it which data applies to which existing element. Is there a mechanism to link new data with existing elements, for example an ID or anything?

This is noticeable if my hierarchy is one level and then later split into groups. Some of the existing circles become the parent group circles rather than creating new ones for it. I do have enter/exit functions but it just does a dumb update as there seems to be no way of linking the existing elements to the new data.

I’m sure there must be a way to bind the two together but for the life of me I can’t find it. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. You might want to edit the question to add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: It is likely that the issue can be solved by adding a key function to the data.binding (second argument of `d3.data` function). c.f. [reference](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_data).

Comment: @Mehdi you are my hero! I have no idea how I missed that. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score -1):

Mehdi answered this in the comments but adding here for anybody else with the same issue.

I was missing a key in the data binding [reference](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_data).

Instead of applying the data using `.data(data)` I needed to add an additional key so that it could be bound properly like `.data(data, function(d) { return d.data.id; })`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).